# CSS z-index bug in IE with two input elements

Tags: css

I'm trying to place two inputs on top of eachother.  The top one is active and has a transparent background, the bottom one is disabled:

```
<div id="autotest-wrap">
    <input id="autotest" value="ab" />
    <input id="autotest-sugg" value="abc" disabled />
</div>

#autotest {
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
#autotest-sugg {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}​
```

This hits the IE z-index bug.  In IE the disabled one is on top, despite the z-index. I'm having trouble working out the solution.  I setup a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Cs2T/) with an example.  Could someone please provide an explanation of how to work around this bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 doesn't like `background-color: transparent`. It's a known bug.

The workaround is to use a transparent image:

`background: url('path/to/1px-transparent.gif')`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/2Cs2T/2/)

Comment: Awesome. It works now when I use both `background-color: transparent` and `background: url('path/to/1px-transparent.gif')`.  Thanks, that was killing me!